# how to handle date column with null when insert or update in mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis

I have a java bean `BeanA`:

```
public class BeanA {
    
    private Integer id;
    private String dateField;
    // other fields
}
```

And mysql table `bean_a` which contains `date` column `date_field`.

the corresponding mybatis sql looks like:

```
<insert ..>
insert into bean_a(date_field, ..) values
(
<if test="dateField != null and dateField == ''">null,</if>
<if test="dateField != null and dateField != ''">#{dateField},</if>
...
)
</insert>

<update ..>
update bean_a
<set>
<if test="dateField != null && dateField == ''">date_field = null,</if>
<if test="dateField != null && dateField != ''">date_field = #{dateField},</if>
</set>
where id = #{id}
</update>
```

For date field, it includes two cases:

1. user clear its value on UI, in this case we should insert/update `null` to table
2. `BeanA beanA = new BeanA();set other fields exclude dateField;then call dao to update BeanA`, in this case, we should update table without modifying `date_field` because the `dateField` is null.

Is the above a general practice? Is there better practice(because it requires two if check for each insert/update, which maybe repetiton)? Thanks!

Comment: It might depend on the requirements, but I would avoid using special value like `-999999999-01-01` if possible. Also, comparing `Date` against `String` in `test` expression may not work. A common update strategy is 1) get an instance of `BeanA` from DB, 2) bind values submitted from UI to the instance and 3) pass the modified instance when calling `updateBeanA`. This way, those `<if>`s would be unnecessary.

Comment: @ave Thanks, I am using `String` type in java bean for date column and I need to check empty string for insert/update statement. Now, the `String` or `Date` seems similar. For your approach, we need to get the instance and merge before updating, and also need additional check for insert statement. Right?

Comment: I don't understand why you need to exclude `date_field` from the INSERT. If it's excluded, the value of `date_field` still is `NULL`, isn't it?  And `BeanA.dateField` is declared as `LocalDate` in your question. Is there another "bean"?

Comment: @ave sorry, there is misleading about `exclude`. what I mean is `if I declare the dateField as String in BeanA, and if its value is an empty string, then we should ignore it because the empty string cannot be inserted into a date column in database`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the usage of `-999999999-01-01` but I'm guessing you use this value to represent a date that has not been set, and should not be updated? Personally I think this type of logic is a bit hacky, perhaps you could avoid it with extra `isXSet()` methods on your bean?

It's a bit of boilerplate... but you could have `MyBean` and `MyBeanDelta` where the delta represents changes/updates.

Eg

```java
public class MyBean {
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private LocalDate date;

   // getters & setters
}

public class MyBeanDelta {
   private final Long id;
   private final Map<String, Object> fields = new LinkedHashMap<>();

   // constructor

   public Long getId() { return id; }

   public void setName(String) { fields.put("name", name); }
   public boolean isNameSet() { return fields.contains("name"); }
   public String getName() { return (String) fields.get("name"); }

   public void setDate(LocalDate date) { fields.put("date", date); }
   public boolean isDateSet() { return fields.contains("date"); }
   public LocalDate getDate() { return (LocalDate) fields.get("date"); }
}
```

Then you could do

```java
@Mapper
public interface MyBeanMapper
   void insert(MyBean bean);
   void update(MyBeanDelta delta);
}
```

And

```xml
<insert id="insert">
   insert into my_bean (id, name, date)
   values (
     #{id}, 
     #{name,javaType=java.lang.String}, 
     #{date,javaType=java.time.LocalDate}
   )
</insert>
<update id="update">
   update my_bean
   <set>
      <if test=#{nameSet}>name = #{name,javaType=java.lang.String},</if>
      <if test=#{dateSet}>date = #{date,javaType=java.time.LocalDate},</if>
   </set>
   where id = #{id}
</update>
```

Comment: Thanks, I got you point, it is appropriate. this approach requires two class for each java bean,  what if there are many java bean, then it cause the number of class increase dramatically?

Comment: As I said... it's a bit of boilerplate. Perhaps you could have your own custom `@Delta` annotation which you put on your beans then generate all the `XDelta` classes via an [annotation processor](https://www.baeldung.com/java-annotation-processing-builder)

Answer (score 0):

Note: I'm not quite sure what you're doing with `dateField == '-999999999-01-01'` but that looks like bad practice to me. I'll ignore that

The problem here is that `PreparedStatement.setObject(int, Object)` does not work for null because the driver doesn't know which type of null to pass to the db. The good news is that `PreparedStatement.setObject(int, Object, int sqlType)` does support null. We just need to give Mybatis enough information to determine the type so it can call the three args method.

If you include the `jdbcType` and/or the `javaType` inside the parameter placeholder, Mybatis can then pass the type to `PreparedStatement.setObject(...)`

See [sqlmap parameters](https://mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#parameters) and [java.sql.Types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Types.html)

Eg one of the following will work

```xml
<update id="updateBeanA">
    update bean_a 
    set date_field = #{dateField,jdbcType=DATE} 
    where id = #{id}
</update>
```

or

```xml
<update id="updateBeanA">
    update bean_a 
    set date_field = #{dateField,javaType=java.time.LocalDate} 
    where id = #{id}
</update>
```

Comment: Thanks, if just `set date_field = #{dateField,javaType=java.time.LocalDate}`, then this sql will set `null` to `date_field` for case `BeanA b = new BeanA();set other fields exclude dateField;update table;`, while in this case, we shouldn't update `date_field` to null, it should be ignored.

Comment: Ok... well I guess you'll put back your wierd `<if test="dateField == '-999999999-01-01">` logic or have some other mechanism to determine if a field should be set

Comment: what if this approach `1. declare dateField as String in BeanA; 2. create a custom mybatis type handler such that convert empty string to null; 3. set date_field = #{dateField,javaType=java.time.LocalDate, typeHandler=customHandler} in insert statement and <if test="dateField != null">date_field = #{dateField,javaType=java.time.LocalDate, typeHandler=customHandler}</if>`. is this a general or good practice?

Comment: See my other answer, you shouldn't really be using empty string or `-999999999-01-01`  to represent some special state... sounds quite hacky to me